# Detect if "Large Text" accessibility option is enabled on Android

Tags: android, accessibility, android-a11y

How can I programatically detect if "Large Text" accessibility option is enabled on Android?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

if Large Text is set, android changes the font scale , so you can detect using

```
Configuration c = getResources().getConfiguration();
float scale = c.fontScale;
```

if scale is greater than 1 then it is large text.